# 2006 chevy equinox overheating

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, overheating, equinox

My 2006 chevy equinox was overheating, temp gauge fluctuated up and down, and blower was not working at all. Also fans would come on and stay on for about 5 minutes after ignition was turned off.
I changed the coolant temperature sensor and everything got fixed.  I drove for about a day. Like a doof, I decided to bleed air out through bleeding screw on engine block. I had the front of the car on top of a curb. I loosened the screw and turned car on. But when I turned heater on, blower did not go on. I went ahead and bled some air out. When I started driving, I noticed all previous symptoms had returned. 
I changed coolant temp sensor again and thermostat. But it did not get fixed again.
Dont know why its overheating. And why is blower not working???  Why did the coolant temp sensor fix the problems the first time?

Comment: Have you tested for a failed cylinder head or cylinder head gasket?